# How do I overwrite input items in session in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

When the input screen is opened when the screen is displayed, input items on the screen are set from session information.
However, although jQuery performs display switching based on the value of the input item on the screen, switching is performed based on the initial value (on the program), not the session information.
Presumably, jQuery display switching is performed before session information is set (the initial data is set in the input item).

For example, in the following source, a session is set, but the screen is displayed with the content of category = 1.

And the point of concern is that the following warning is displayed.

> [Vue warn]: Avoid adding reactive properties to a Vue instance or its root $ data at runtime-declare it upfront in the data option.

```
data: {
    url: "",
    category: 1,
    errors: {},
},
created: function() {
    let count_data = 0;
    for (let key in old_data) {
        if (old_data[key] != null && old_data[key] != "") {
            count_data += 1;
        }
    }
    if(count_data > 0) {
        for(let key in old_data){
            this.$set(this, key, old_data[key]);
        }
    }else{
        let that = this;
        axios.get('api/getSession')
            .then(res => {
                Object.entries(res.data).map(function(data){
                    that.$set(that, data[0], data[1]);
                });
            })
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That console message is generated whenever a new property is added to the object returned from data. You shouldn't be getting that message for properties like "category" or "url", but you will if something else is added.

Try generating console messages wherever `$set` is called to ensure that `key` or `data[0]` is not a new unknown property. If it is, try adding it to the data object as a null or empty string.